# After creating war file My spring boot project cannot run with java- jar command

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I created a  new Java project by using jhipster with springboot, liquidbase, hibernate exc. technologies but when i try to deploy my project by calling "java -jar ......SNAPSHOT.war" file, it shows error like

```
"The following profiles are active: prod
   2019-03-29 17:12:25.912  WARN 21772 --- [           main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered 
during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/work/workspaceAngular/puantaj-hesaplama/target/puantaj-hesaplama-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/com/sbb/puantajhesaplama/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#aa22f1c' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#aa22f1c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/sbb/puantajhesaplama/config/LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem at `CustomAuditEventRepository` this class

Share your code with gist.github.com

Comment: But in jhipster document, says that" If you are on Windows, use: java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" pom.xml is generated by jhipster  jhipster.tech/production/#build –

Comment: this repository is private. make it public so that i can see the code

Comment: İ made it public now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it with `java -jar` you have to build a JAR not a WAR.

So in your pom.xml

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: so, what can i do  to run war ?

Comment: You have to deploy it to a web container like Tomcat

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: But in jhipster document,  If you are on Windows, use:

java -jar jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#build